# android.view.RenderNode JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, weak-references

I am using UIautomator for our android app running high volume usage tests. After certain amount of time I get a large amount of weak global references to android.view.RenderNode which causes to app to crash. To me it looks like it has something to with internal part of the android.view.View class. I am wondering if there is a way to clean up these weak global references before hitting the table limit. Here is a trace:

```
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] weak global reference table dump:
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51199: 0x1ad5e2f8 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51198: 0x1ad5e118 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51197: 0x1ad56fe8 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51196: 0x1ad56fb8 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51195: 0x1ad56f88 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51194: 0x1ad56ce8 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51193: 0x1ad56868 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51192: 0x1ad56688 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51191: 0x1ad565c8 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51190: 0x1ad56598 android.view.RenderNode
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]   Summary:
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of org.chromium.android_webview.AwQuotaManagerBridge
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         3 of byte[] (2016 elements) (3 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         3 of byte[] (6864 elements) (3 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (7392 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (9408 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         5 of byte[] (12544 elements) (5 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         4 of byte[] (13720 elements) (4 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (22500 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (23520 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         9 of byte[] (28224 elements) (9 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (32592 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]        27 of byte[] (36100 elements) (27 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]        10 of byte[] (37632 elements) (10 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         2 of byte[] (47432 elements) (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         2 of byte[] (48400 elements) (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]        19 of byte[] (50176 elements) (19 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         3 of byte[] (63504 elements) (3 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         2 of byte[] (64512 elements) (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         3 of byte[] (108192 elements) (3 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         4 of byte[] (112896 elements) (4 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         4 of byte[] (147000 elements) (4 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         1 of byte[] (178084 elements)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         2 of byte[] (179776 elements) (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         5 of byte[] (367236 elements) (5 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         2 of byte[] (1666560 elements) (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         6 of dalvik.system.PathClassLoader (2 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]        16 of java.lang.DexCache (16 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]     51062 of android.view.RenderNode (51062 unique instances)
04-06 10:42:05.205 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] 
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75986698 self=0xb088b400
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=4806 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4c25534
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2324 stm=4003 core=0 HZ=100
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xbf0bd000-0xbf0bf000 stackSize=8MB
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "JNI weak global reference table lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f6e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f35e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c35b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527bca  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+330)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 002cd198  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art22IndirectReferenceTable3AddEjPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+376)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039323b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt16AddWeakGlobalRefEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+91)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00403b64  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+788)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0013f952  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI6NewRefEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectNS_15IndirectRefKindE+1106)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001396c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI16NewWeakGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+57)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 000c2541  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 00af872c  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_view_RenderNode_nCreate__Ljava_lang_String_2+136)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.RenderNode.nCreate(Native method)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.RenderNode.<init>(RenderNode.java:137)
04-06 10:42:05.316 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.RenderNode.create(RenderNode.java:161)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4026)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4146)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1016)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1073)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0e863a9a> (a java.lang.Object[])
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
04-06 10:42:05.317 F/art     ( 4806): art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) ...
```

Comment: Oneo possibility that comes to mind is that your tester does not let the Garbage Collector time to run. You can dir

Comment: There seem to be other traces of similar crash, e.g. https://blog.csdn.net/firedancer0089/article/details/78224100 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48980541/192373.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are leaking `android.view.View` instances, unless you really need over 51200 of them? Here's some simple code to force the error and demonstrate the limit:

```
new Thread() {
  HashSet<View> aLotOfViews = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Log.d("test", "Hi, I need a lot of views");

    for (int i = 0; i < 59000; i++) {
      aLotOfViews.add(new View(getApplicationContext()));
      if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        Log.d("test", "I have some views: " + aLotOfViews.size());
      }
    }

    Log.d("test", "I have a lot of views: " + aLotOfViews.size());
  }
}.start();
```

I suggest trying the memory profiling tools from Google to find the leak: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler